# Encoding MKV File Without Changing Header Information

Tags: ffmpeg, video, encoding, matroska

I captured a video using a `Kinect Azure SDK` device. This captured video (.mkv container) has three tracks: `Color`, `Depth` and `IR`. I extracted the Color track using `MKVToolNIX`. I could playback this RGB track using `Azure Kinect Viewer (v.1.4.1)`. However, when I encode a video using `FFmpeg`, the command is given below. I can not playback the video using Azure Kinect Viewer. I get a message:

> Failed to open Recording

```
ffmpeg -i .\RGB.mkv -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -crf 18 RGG_Enc.mkv
```

I tried with different codecs (H.264, H.265, VP9, VP10, MJPEG) with different settings, and with different softwares such as `XMedia Recode`, `HandBrake` softwares to encode the video, but could not play the video in `Azure Kinect Viewer`. Can someone suggest to me what to do?

This [example video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/107kpyObNsPXcxMSg7Zl0KdA5_Hj0l52B/view) contains only one color track (`.MKV`) from the original video. I am able to play this video using Azure Kinect Viewer.